# Gradle composite build. Project not found. includeBuild not working?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I have 2 projects, my-app and string-utils.  My-app depends on string-utils.  When building my-app I get:

> "Project with path ':string-utils' could not be found in root project 'my-app'

Shouldn't includeBuild work here?

My Gradle scan is [here](https://scans.gradle.com/s/7o56bnriqxfj6).

```
├── my-app
│   ├── build
│   ├── build.gradle
│   ├── settings.gradle
│   └── src
└── string-utils
    ├── build
    ├── build.gradle
    ├── settings.gradle
    └── src
```

/my-app/settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'my-app'
includeBuild '../string-utils'
```

/my-app/build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'idea'
}
group "org.sample"
version "1.0"
application {
    mainClassName = "org.sample.myapp.Main"
}
dependencies {
  implementation project(':string-utils')
}
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

/string-utils/settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'string-utils'
```

When running:

```
/my-app$ gradle build --scan --info

Initialized native services in: /home/andrew/.gradle/native
The client will now receive all logging from the daemon (pid: 202204). The daemon log file: /home/andrew/.gradle/daemon/6.2.1/daemon-202204.out.log
Starting 4th build in daemon [uptime: 38 mins 14.32 secs, performance: 99%, non-heap usage: 20% of 268.4 MB]
Using 128 worker leases.
Starting Build
Compiling settings file '/tmp/5/my-app/settings.gradle' using BuildScriptTransformer.
Settings evaluated using settings file '/tmp/5/my-app/settings.gradle'.
Projects loaded. Root project using build file '/tmp/5/my-app/build.gradle'.
Included projects: [root project 'my-app']
[composite-build] Configuring build: /tmp/5/string-utils

Configure project :string-utils
Evaluating project ':string-utils' using build file '/tmp/5/string-utils/build.gradle'.
Registering project ':string-utils' in composite build. Will substitute for module ':string-utils'.

Configure project :
Evaluating root project 'my-app' using build file '/tmp/5/my-app/build.gradle'.
Compiling build file '/tmp/5/my-app/build.gradle' using SubsetScriptTransformer.
Compiling build file '/tmp/5/my-app/build.gradle' using BuildScriptTransformer.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/tmp/5/my-app/build.gradle' line: 19

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-app'.

Project with path ':string-utils' could not be found in root project 'my-app'.
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Fixed.  Needed to replace

```
implementation project(':string-utils')
```

with

```
implementation "org.sample:string-utils"
```

Comment: Where exactly should on expect "org.sample:string-utils" to be defined? Where did you get this string from?

Comment: "my-app" and "string-utils" are the names of my two projects.  You can name yours whatever you like.

Comment: Where is the 'org.sample' defined?

Comment: That's just the namespace of the project.  The first line would be "package org.sample.string-utils" or whatever you like.  The other project would have "package org.sample.my-app"

Comment: Where is the namespace defined?

Comment: See this page for package and namespace info: 
 https://cs.smu.ca/~porter/csc/465/notes/javapl_packages.html

Comment: @Scorb "namespace" (actually the groupId) of the project is defined in your gradle file in a line that looks like `group = "org.sample"`. it should related to you class packages, but it is not necessarily.